# Delphi save file iso-8859-9 encode

Tags: delphi, encoding, encode

I with Delphi "memo1.lines.text" I would like to record in ISO-8859-9 format(encoding).
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var
  Encoding: TEncoding;
....
Encoding := TEncoding.GetEncoding('iso-8859-9');
try
  Memo1.Lines.SaveToFile(filename, Encoding);
finally
  Encoding.Free;
end;
```

Comment: @DavidHeffernan OK, my mistake, sorry.

Comment: Thank you very much bro. So I did not expect a simple answer. I am ashamed of myself. :D I did some research for an entire day for this.

Comment: @Erkan1525 no need to be ashamed we all here to learn form each other. Welcome to SO